# Password protected VBA but code still visible

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel macro file(.xlsm), when I open the VBA editor, on the left panel I right click on `VBA project XYZ` and click on `VBAProject properties`, it prompts for a password. This indicates that VBA is password protected. However, I am still able to see the macro codes in modules/sheets.

1. Is that possible and if yes then what's the point here in protection?
2. Though I am able to see the code, when I try to add a reference, I again get that password prompt. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you or the author haven't clicked on `Locked project from viewing` while protecting the VBA Project.

[image]

Also you need to close and re-open the workbook for the Lock Effect to take place after `Locked project from viewing` is `checked`

**Your Questions**

> Is that possible and if yes then what's the point here in protection?

Yes it is possible. The intention here could be to ensure that you don't make any changes to say references as you have already experienced. `OR` someone simply forgot to click on `Locked project from viewing` like shown above.

> Though I am able to see the code, when I try to add a reference, I again get that password prompt. Why?

As mentioned above, since the VBA Project is locked, you cannot make changes like adding a reference.

Comment: Thanks @Siddharth Rout that makes perfect sense. I just wonder if there's any particular reason for MS to keep this ('Lock project for viewing') option. What's the point if one can view the code even if not allowed to add a reference. Also as you said, there's always a chance for user to forget clicking that option.

Comment: `What's the point if one can view the code even if not allowed to add a reference.` Probably to let a user understand what the code does? Now that is beside the point that you can add/delete code but not add/delete references :)